# Windows 7 Software Driver Installation out of nowhere with Asian symbols

Tags: windows-7, drivers, virus

I got the following Software Driver Installation screen out of nowhere. Screen language is in German, so that is fine. I quickly aborted the search attempt.

[image]

What is/was that?

---

Here is the matching block from `setupapi.dev.log`:

```
>>>  [Device Install (Hardware initiated) - USB\VID_0BDB&PID_1910\328C92879D3A5690]
>>>  Section start 2015/09/24 19:02:47.287
     ump: Creating Install Process: DrvInst.exe 19:02:47.292
     ndv: Retrieving device info...
     ndv: Setting device parameters...
     ndv: Searching just Driver Store...
     dvi: {Build Driver List} 19:02:47.381
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910&rev_0100
     dvi:           usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_03&subclass_00&prot_00
     dvi:           usb\class_03&subclass_00
     dvi:           usb\class_03
     cpy:      Policy is set to make all digital signatures equal.
     dvi:      Enumerating INFs from path list 'C:\Windows\INF'
     inf:      Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi:      Created Driver Node:
     dvi:           HardwareID   - USB\Class_03
     dvi:           InfName      - C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf
     dvi:           DevDesc      - USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:           DrvDesc      - USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:           Provider     - Microsoft
     dvi:           Mfg          - (Standardsystemgeräte)
     dvi:           ModelsSec    - Standard.NTamd64
     dvi:           InstallSec   - HID_Inst
     dvi:           ActualSec    - HID_Inst.NT
     dvi:           Rank         - 0x00ff3202
     dvi:           Signer       - Microsoft Windows
     dvi:           Signer Score - INBOX
     dvi:           DrvDate      - 06/21/2006
     dvi:           Version      - 6.1.7601.18199
     inf:      Searched 1 potential matches in published INF directory
     inf:      Searched 35 INFs in directory: 'C:\Windows\INF'
     dvi: {Build Driver List - exit(0x00000000)} 19:02:47.917
     ndv: Selecting best match from just Driver Store...
     dvi: {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV} 19:02:47.918
     dvi:      No class installer for '???w'
     dvi:      No CoInstallers found
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 19:02:47.922
     dvi:           {Select Best Driver}
     dvi:                Selected driver installs from section [HID_Inst] in 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'.
     dvi:                Class GUID of device changed to: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}.
     dvi:                Set selected driver complete.
     dvi:                Selected:
     dvi:                     Description - [USB-Eingabegerät]
     dvi:                     InfFile     - [c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf]
     dvi:                     Section     - [HID_Inst]
     dvi:                     Signer      - [Microsoft Windows]
     dvi:                     Rank        - [0x00ff3202]
     dvi:           {Select Best Driver - exit(0x00000000)}
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV - exit(0x00000000)} 19:02:47.933
     inf: Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\INF\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     ndv: Searching Windows Update for drivers... 19:02:47.962
     inf: Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\INF\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     ndv: Acquired WU search serialization mutex. 19:02:47.965
     ndv: Received request to cancel Windows Update search.
     ndv: About to release WU search serialization mutex. 19:03:21.204
     ndv: Windows Update driver search cancelled. 19:03:21.205
     ndv: Searching Driver Store and Device Path...
     dvi: {Build Driver List} 19:03:21.207
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910&rev_0100
     dvi:           usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_03&subclass_00&prot_00
     dvi:           usb\class_03&subclass_00
     dvi:           usb\class_03
     cpy:      Policy is set to make all digital signatures equal.
     dvi:      Enumerating INFs from path list 'C:\Windows\inf'
     inf:      Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi:      Created Driver Node:
     dvi:           HardwareID   - USB\Class_03
     dvi:           InfName      - C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf
     dvi:           DevDesc      - USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:           DrvDesc      - USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:           Provider     - Microsoft
     dvi:           Mfg          - (Standardsystemgeräte)
     dvi:           ModelsSec    - Standard.NTamd64
     dvi:           InstallSec   - HID_Inst
     dvi:           ActualSec    - HID_Inst.NT
     dvi:           Rank         - 0x00ff3202
     dvi:           Signer       - Microsoft Windows
     dvi:           Signer Score - INBOX
     dvi:           DrvDate      - 06/21/2006
     dvi:           Version      - 6.1.7601.18199
     inf:      Searched 1 potential matches in published INF directory
     inf:      Searched 35 INFs in directory: 'C:\Windows\inf'
     dvi: {Build Driver List - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.442
     ndv: Selecting best match from Driver Store (including Device Path)...
     dvi: {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV} 19:03:21.443
     dvi:      No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:      No CoInstallers found
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.446
     dvi:           {Select Best Driver}
     dvi:                Selected driver installs from section [HID_Inst] in 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'.
     dvi:                Class GUID of device changed to: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}.
     dvi:                Set selected driver complete.
     dvi:                Selected:
     dvi:                     Description - [USB-Eingabegerät]
     dvi:                     InfFile     - [c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf]
     dvi:                     Section     - [HID_Inst]
     dvi:                     Signer      - [Microsoft Windows]
     dvi:                     Rank        - [0x00ff3202]
     dvi:           {Select Best Driver - exit(0x00000000)}
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.455
     inf: {SetupCopyOEMInf: C:\Windows\INF\input.inf} 19:03:21.460
     inf:      Driver Store location: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf
     inf:      Published Inf Path: C:\Windows\INF\input.inf
     inf: {SetupCopyOEMInf exit (0x00000050)} 19:03:21.465
     dvi: Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:      usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910&rev_0100
     dvi:      usb\vid_0bdb&pid_1910
     dvi: Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:      usb\class_03&subclass_00&prot_00
     dvi:      usb\class_03&subclass_00
     dvi:      usb\class_03
     inf: Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi: Selected driver installs from section [HID_Inst] in 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'.
     dvi: Class GUID of device changed to: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}.
     dvi: Set selected driver complete.
     ndv: Driver selected, now performing install...
     ndv: {Core Device Install} 19:03:21.478
     inf:      Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\INF\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
!    pol:      Selected driver node does not match this device (force-install)
     inf:      Opened PNF: 'C:\Windows\INF\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi:      {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL} 19:03:21.533
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           No CoInstallers found
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.536
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL - exit(0xe000020e)} 19:03:21.537
     ndv:      Installing files...
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICEFILES} 19:03:21.538
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.541
     dvi:                {Install FILES}
     inf:                     Opened PNF: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT]}
     inf:                          Copyfiles=HID_Inst.CopyFiles.NT  (input.inf line 489)
     flq:                          CopyFiles from an inbox inf.
     cpy:                          Open PnpLockdownPolicy: Err=2. This is OK. Use LockDownPolicyDefault
     flq:                          QueueSingleCopy...
     flq:                          Inf     : 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceInf: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceSection: [sourcedisksfiles]
     flq:                          Source root path based on SourceInf
     flq:                          SourceRootPath: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                               CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                                    CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                                    SourceRootPath - 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                                    SourceFilename - 'hidusb.sys'
     flq:                                    TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS'
     flq:                                    TargetFilename - 'hidusb.sys'
     flq:                                    SourceDesc     - 'windows cd'
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:                          QueueSingleCopy...
     flq:                          Inf     : 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceInf: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceSection: [sourcedisksfiles]
     flq:                          Source root path based on SourceInf
     flq:                          SourceRootPath: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                               CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                                    CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                                    SourceRootPath - 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                                    SourceFilename - 'hidclass.sys'
     flq:                                    TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS'
     flq:                                    TargetFilename - 'hidclass.sys'
     flq:                                    SourceDesc     - 'windows cd'
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:                          QueueSingleCopy...
     flq:                          Inf     : 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceInf: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf'
     flq:                          SourceSection: [sourcedisksfiles]
     flq:                          Source root path based on SourceInf
     flq:                          SourceRootPath: 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                               CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY}
     flq:                                    CopyStyle      - 0x09000000
     flq:                                    SourceRootPath - 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d'
     flq:                                    SourceFilename - 'hidparse.sys'
     flq:                                    TargetDirectory- 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS'
     flq:                                    TargetFilename - 'hidparse.sys'
     flq:                                    SourceDesc     - 'windows cd'
     flq:                               {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     flq:                          {FILE_QUEUE_COPY exit(0x00000000)}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT] exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                     Processing co-installer registration section [HID_Inst.NT.CoInstallers].
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.CoInstallers]}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.CoInstallers] exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                     Co-installers registered.
     dvi:                     {Install INTERFACES}
     dvi:                          Installing section [HID_Inst.NT.Interfaces]
     dvi:                     {Install INTERFACES exit 00000000}
     dvi:                {Install FILES exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICEFILES - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.590
     ndv:      Pruning file queue...
     dvi:      {_SCAN_FILE_QUEUE}
     flq:           ScanQ flags=620
     flq:                SPQ_SCAN_PRUNE_COPY_QUEUE
     flq:                SPQ_SCAN_FILE_COMPARISON
     flq:                SPQ_SCAN_ACTIVATE_DRP
     flq:           ScanQ number of copy nodes=3
     flq:           File 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidusb.sys' pruned from copy.
     sig:           Using catalog 'C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Package_1_for_KB2862335~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.cat'.
     cpy:           DrpSetRegFileProt 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidusb.sys' Status=0 Class=Inbox Windows protected
     flq:           File 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidclass.sys' pruned from copy.
     sig:           Using catalog 'C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Package_3_for_KB2862335~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.cat'.
     cpy:           DrpSetRegFileProt 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidclass.sys' Status=0 Class=Inbox Windows protected
     flq:           File 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidparse.sys' pruned from copy.
     sig:           Using catalog 'C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Package_3_for_KB2862335~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.cat'.
     cpy:           DrpSetRegFileProt 'C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidparse.sys' Status=0 Class=Inbox Windows protected
     flq:           ScanQ action=200 DoPruning=32
     flq:           ScanQ end Validity flags=620 CopyNodes=0
     dvi:      {_SCAN_FILE_QUEUE exit(0, 0x00000000)}
     ndv:      Committing file queue...
     flq:      {_commit_file_queue}
     flq:           CommitQ DelNodes=0 RenNodes=0 CopyNodes=0
     flq:           CommitQ early exit: No nodes are queued
     flq:      {_commit_file_queue exit OK}
     ndv:      Registering CoInstallers...
     dvi:      {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS} 19:03:21.832
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.835
     inf:                Opened PNF: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     inf:                {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.CoInstallers]}
     inf:                {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.CoInstallers] exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                Co-installers registered.
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.839
     ndv:      Installing interfaces...
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLINTERFACES} 19:03:21.840
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           No CoInstallers found
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.842
     dvi:                {Install INTERFACES}
     inf:                     Opened PNF: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi:                     Installing section [HID_Inst.NT.Interfaces]
     dvi:                {Install INTERFACES exit 00000000}
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLINTERFACES - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.845
     ndv:      Installing device...
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE} 19:03:21.846
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.847
     dvi:                {Install DEVICE}
     inf:                     Opened PNF: 'c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\input.inf_amd64_neutral_fccb715ac7d8c66d\input.inf' ([strings.0407])
     dvi:                     Writing BASIC Logical Configurations...
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT]}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT] exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                     Processing Registry/Property directives...
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT]}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT] exit (0x00000000)}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.Hw]}
     inf:                          DelReg=HID_Inst.DelReg.NT.HW  (input.inf line 492)
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.Hw] exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                     {Writing Device Properties}
     dvi:                          Provider name=Microsoft
     dvi:                          DriverDate 06/21/2006
     dvi:                          DriverVersion=6.1.7601.18199
     dvi:                          Class name=HIDClass
     dvi:                          Manufacturer=(Standardsystemgeräte)
     dvi:                          Matching DeviceID=generic_hid_device
     dvi:                          Strong Name=input.inf:Standard.NTamd64:HID_Inst:6.1.7601.18199::generic_hid_device:usb\class_03&subclass_01:usb\class_03
     dvi:                          Additional Software Requested
     dvi:                     {Writing Device Properties - Complete}
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.Services]}
     inf:                          AddService=HidUsb,0x00000002,HID_Service_Inst  (input.inf line 504)
     inf:                          ServiceType=1  (input.inf line 520)
     inf:                          StartType=3  (input.inf line 521)
     inf:                          ErrorControl=0  (input.inf line 522)
     inf:                          ServiceBinary=C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hidusb.sys  (input.inf line 523)
     inf:                          DisplayName="Microsoft HID Class-Treiber"  (input.inf line 519)
     inf:                          LoadOrderGroup="extended base"  (input.inf line 524)
     dvi:                          Add Service: Modified existing service 'HidUsb'.
     inf:                     {Install Inf Section [HID_Inst.NT.Services] exit(0x00000000)}
     dvi:                     Updated reflected section names for: input.inf
     dvi:                {Install DEVICE exit (0x00000000)}
     dvi:                Writing common driver property settings.
     dvi:                     DriverDescription=USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:                     DeviceDisplayName=USB-Eingabegerät
     dvi:                Install Device: Removing device sub-tree. 19:03:21.939
     dvi:                Install Device: Removing device sub-tree completed. 19:03:21.962
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.965
     dvi:      {DIF_NEWDEVICEWIZARD_FINISHINSTALL} 19:03:21.965
     dvi:           No class installer for 'USB-Eingabegerät'
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 19:03:21.967
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_NEWDEVICEWIZARD_FINISHINSTALL - exit(0xe000020e)} 19:03:21.968
     ndv:      Device install status=0x00000000
     ndv:      Performing device install final cleanup...
     ndv:      Additional software is requested so a WER report should be sent, but the sending of WER reports from drvinst has been suppressed.
     ndv: {Core Device Install - exit(0x00000000)} 19:03:21.972
     ump: Server install process exited with code 0x00000000 19:03:21.977
<<<  Section end 2015/09/24 19:03:21.980
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]
```

Comment: The characters seems to be Japanese or Chinese. Translation with respect to Japanese is : `Shield Co., Ltd. Zhu w`

Comment: Do you have any devices or software in your machine, related to Shield ? The error says the device was removed.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV Thanks for that hint. I wasn't able to extract the symbols with some online OCR tools. Could you please paste the symbols as a comment here?

Comment: @Nikhil_CV I didn't add or remove any hardware. I canceled the search therefore it says "device removed".

Comment: Text you request could not be added here. Here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/7gFfpuSD. Paste Valid for a day only

Comment: Thanks. It does not matter, that the symbol for `shield` has 1 to 2 strokes more than the one on the popup?

Comment: May be because of the language? IDK... If you got this popup all on a sudden from air, you should inspect your `device manager ` and `Windows event viewer` to check if something is problematic. Worst case is some surveillance/rootkit/bootkit  infection. If you have time, seek help from free forums like `bleeping computer, geeks to go` to determine the presence of infection.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd fill in the answer as I got the same pop-up on a Dell E6420. This is related to the Dell 5550 HSPA+ broadband card that for some reason tries to installa HID-driver after a fresh windows installation. To to show the proof:

From event manager:
Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service HidUsb for Device Instance ID USB\VID_0BDB&PID_1910\49CFFA80B4E28620 with the following status: 0.

Then looking at VID/PID going to USB device explorer:
[USBview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBQVD.png)